# Insert non-editable content in Editable Div, Browser Compatibility problems

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, contenteditable

I'm trying to put some non-editable content inside an editable div on html page.
The following works exactly the way I need in FireFox, but Internet Explorer behaves wierd:

```html
<div id="EditableDiv" contenteditable="true" style="height:100px;width:500px;font-family:Consolas;letter-spacing:1px;padding:5px;color:white;background-color:black;">
  0.5 * <span contenteditable="false" unselectable="on">{NonEditableText}</span> / 100
</div>
```

I have the following three problems related to behavior in Firefox vs. in Internet Explorer:

1. Click on the non-editable content. It highlights the whole span as expected in Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer.
2. Deleting the div contents is very erratic:

   To test this, position your cursor at the beginning of text and start deleting from left to right character by character.

   Notice that in Firefox it works as expected. The non-editable span gets deleted all at once (like a single character).

   In Internet Explorer there are two problems:

   - Random spaces are inserted.
   - The non-editable content gets deleted character by character, and not a single element as a whole.

[image: Difference between Firefox and Internet Explorer]